# Search in reportviewer between 2 datas

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

Search between 2 datas  textbox1.text & textbox2.text
Here is my code for search for NAME, it already works know i need search between 2 datas

```
  Try
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then
            Dim keyword As String = Me.TextBox1.Text.Trim()
            Me.tableBindingSource.Filter =
               "(Name_Lastname LIKE '%" & keyword & "%')"
            ' "OR (Data LIKE '%" & keyword & "%')"
            Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
        Else
            Me.tableBindingSource.RemoveFilter()
            fatura_form_Load(sender, e)


        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.Message.ToString(),
                        "Error 17",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Finally
        Me.TextBox1.Focus()

    End Try
```

Here is the code search just for one data
 `' "OR (Data LIKE '%" & keyword & "%')"`

but i need search from 2 textboxes,

Answer (score 0):

DataView RowFilter supports >= and <= for strings.

Here's an example:

```
    Dim dt as new System.Data.DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Str")
    dt.Rows.Add(new Object(){"0234"})
    dt.Rows.Add(new Object(){"12345"})
    dt.Rows.Add(new Object(){"12346"})
    dt.Rows.Add(new Object(){"234"})
    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Str >= '0' And Str < '2'"
    Console.WriteLine(dt.DefaultView.Count) ' Shows 3
```